# Reading new message in Python Discord

Tags: python, discord.py

I am working with Python Discord. I need a function that, when called, will receive new messages. I know about

```py
async def on_message(message)
```

But I need to read new messages only when I call function.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a variable that detects if the command has been run, for example:

`record_messages = False`

Once you run the command set it to true

`record_messages = True`

Then you can use `async def on_message(message)` along with the variable to record the messages if the command has been run:

```
async def on_message(message):
    if record_message == True:
        #Record Messages
    else:
        pass
```